# Does ITIL has a specific area dedicated to Software Quality Managment?

Tags: software-development, itil

i'm new to ITIL and i have been looking for an area in ITIL, that specifically talks about SQM. Does this area exists expecifically for Software?

If it exists it would be great if anybody could point me out where it is. I have been looking for ITIL SQM but i haven't found anything that points out specifically to this. I have been told that ITIL has a series of steps, phases or criteria for doing SQM, but i don't know if this is right or if it comes by a different name or concept.

Thanks!

Comment: ITIL is primarily for service delivery. Why do you want to treat software development as service delivery?

Comment: Because some companies nowadays stop selling licenses (like SAP/Oracle/MS/..) and propagate "software as a service" (Yes I know its a marketing scam, but if you have to ride the wave....)

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there are "only" [processes/guidelines for release management](https://www.itilnews.com/index.php?pagename=ITIL_release_management) and about [Knowledge Management](https://www.itilnews.com/index.php?pagename=Knowledge_Management_The_ITIL_Quality_Management_Aspect) from which you could derive SMQS.
This academic paper will give you some background to what impacts ITIL has/had -
[Research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255725182_ITIL_implementation_The_Role_of_ITIL_software_and_project_quality) There are lot of books around, perhaps some point you in the direction you search for